# Change class of elements in list and save with element name

Tags: r, list, rename, spatial

I have a list of elements of type "`im`"

```
mylist
$sp1
$sp2
$sp3
```

and I want to convert them to a list of elements of class "`SpatialGridDataFrame`"

This works for a single object of class "`im`":

```
a <- mylist$sp1
b <- as(a, "SpatialGridDataFrame")
```

Then I want to save each element in the new list b as a .TIFF file, with the name of each element in the list (sp1.TIFF, sp2.TIFF, etc.)

This also works for a single object in package "rgdal":

```
writeGDAL(b, "sp1.TIFF")
```

Any clue?

Comment: Do you want to have a list of SpatialGridDataFrame or just save your list of im objects? you can't do a loop over a list to save it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lapply` to loop over the `names` of you list

```
mylist.df <- lapply(names(mylist), 
                       function(x) {
                            b <- as(mylist[[x]], "SpatialGridDataFrame")
                            writeGDAL(b,paste(x,".TIFF",sep=''))
                            b
                       })
```

here you get your list converted and your object saved.

Comment: I got this error (D is “mylist”)
Error: unexpected string constant in:
"                 b <-as(D[x], "SpatialGridDataFrame")
                 writeGDAL(b,paste(x, ".TIFF", sep''"
Then I did the first part only:
> D.df <- lapply(names(D),
+                function(x) {
+               as(D[x], "SpatialGridDataFrame")
+                })
Error in as(D[x], "SpatialGridDataFrame") : 
  no method or default for coercing “list” to “SpatialGridDataFrame”

Comment: @rob debugging tool? here we have problem because I can't test my code. I don't have a reproducible example to dot it. But this code works.

Comment: @rob do you still have a prblem?

Comment: Yes, indeed, I'm just getting started with loops and functions. I still have the problem mentioned above. Maybe in "writeGDAL(b,paste(x,".TIFF",sep=''))" the functions loops through the list b and not through the elements of the list? Or I could send you an .RData file with my list.

Comment: it is writeGDAL(b,paste(x,".TIFF",sep=''))copy and paste it please.